# Singleton и абстрактный класс

Tags: ооп, php

Решил поюзать паттерн `Singleton` для общего развития, развития особого не получилось)). Несмотря на обилие описаний, так и не понял, дает ли он какое-нибудь преимущество по сравнению, скажем, с обычным абстрактным классом? Так у меня создалось впечатление, что возникает больше неудобств, а обычный абстрактный класс делает все то же самое. Может, я просто не умею его готовить?

Comment: Какие-то у вас странные "знания" в ООП. Вы путаете кислое с зелёным. К слову, одиночка является анти-шаблоном проектирования, потому что нарушает принцип единственной ответственности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У абстрактного класса вообще не может быть экземпляров. Он обычно используется как основа для дальнейшего наследования. У синглтона - всегда один экземпляр. Иногда его используют, например, для создания подключения к БД, или иных сущностей, которые нужны приложению в единственном экземпляре.

Comment: Как раз сделал синглтон для подключения к mySQL. Я вот не вижу никаких предпосылок против того, чтобы релизовать это абстрактным классом. И ИМХО будет удобнее. Я в чем-то ошибаюсь?

Comment: Знаете, возможно, я идиот. Но весь мой опыт говорит, что у абстрактного класса нет экземпляров. Вы можете создать дочерний класс и там сделать экземпляр, но в самом абстрактном классе - нет. 
Нет экземпляра - неоткуда брать свойство с той же самой строкой подключения, например.

Comment: Нет! Идиот походу тут я)) На самом деле, я почему-то в какой-то момент подумал, что абстрактный класс может хранить данные, несмотря на то, что читал об обратном, сейчас взглянул на код и убедился в обратном. И вопрос получился идиотский, но зато разобрался, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А это немного разные вещи. Синглтон - это единственный экземпляр (инстанс) класса. А у абстрактного класса может быть больше одного экземпляра (как реализации дочерних классов).

**UPD**

Так как синглтон - это паттерн, то его можно заменить другой функциональностью, к тому же решение использовать тот или иной паттерн - зависит от разработчика.
Синглтон рекомендуется использовать, когда объект должен быть один и только один, например пул конекшенов к БД, настройки приложения и т.п.

Comment: Так а смысл его использовать?! Какие принципиальные отличия возникают при использовании этого единственного экземпляра и к примеру напрямую абстрактного класса? Неужели отличия только в том, что есть затруднения(я думаю их можно обойти) создать много экземпляров синглтона?

Comment: Подрастете поймете разницу, по поводу затруднений - да, типа есть такие... Если обьявить приватным конструктор и клон то мне очень интересно увидеть каким образом вы будете создавать нескольно экземпляров.<br>
Да и кагбы синглтон придумали для того что-бы обезопасится от этого явления, какое смысл вам в коде сидеть и пыхтеть над тем чтобы создать несколько экземпляров синглтона? И еще раз тонко намекну у нормального синглтона нет никакой абсолютно возможности создавать несколько экземпляров.<br>
Вообще вопрос глупый... Советую почитать книгу типа Шаблоны проэктирования

Comment: "Подрастете поймете разницу" - язвить не обязательно, к сожалению уже не расту, а только развиваюсь. А если ума так много поделитесь, а то хвастать какой я умный каждый может, а на дельный ответ почему-то не способен. От синглтона породить класс можно?! Я вроде прочитал, что можно так если можно породить, значит и экземпляров можно сколько хочешь иметь. То что вопрос глупый я кстати уточнил в комментах, когда понял свою ошибку, если бы абстрактные классы могли бы манипулировать со своими свойствами необходимость в синглтонах бы отпала. Вы хотя бы книгу посоветовали конкретную.

Answer (score 0):

Внесу ясность (скорее для себя, так как ответ на вопрос уже дан)

**Синглтон** - означает, что экземпляр какого-то класса может быть только один. Один и все тут. Никаких "много" в принципе не может быть. Например, как уже было сказано выше, экземпляр, хранящий подключение к базе данных (если база одна).

**Абстрактный класс** - предок структуры классов, у котого есть наследники. НИКАКОГО отношения к приему программирования "Синглтон" напрямую не имеет. Это совершенно другая сущность и у данного класса совершенно другая цель - определить интерфейс для взаимодействия со всеми экземплярами потомков данного класса. НО. Никто не мешает спроектировать абстрактный класс с использованием паттерна "Синглтон". Например, определить абстрактный класс, который будет хранить ОДИН экземпляр подключения к базе данных И этот экземпляр может быть типа одного из потомков данного абстрактного класса - подключение через ОДБС, подключение к SQL, подключение к Ораклу - как варианты.